# I can run MEAN app locally, but can't deploy it

Tags: angular, mongodb, firebase, api, mean

I am trying to deploy a mean app, but I cannot figure out how. My API isn't connecting to my frontend once I deploy, but I can run the application locally on port:3000, but when I try to run it on port:8080 to try and deploy to heroku it doesn't run. I have tried to deploy to firebase, but it just pops up the front-end, and does nothing.
Here is my WWWW/Bin file:

```
enter code here
   #!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('api:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
};
onListening()
console.log("Node server running on port : 3000" );

enter code here
```

Here is. my calls to each endpoint of my api. This is my appointment.services.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Appointment } from './Appointment';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppointmentService {

  private BASE_URL = environment.API_URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAppointments(): Observable<Appointment[]> {
    return this.http.get<Appointment[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/appointments`);
  }

  createAppointment(appointmentDate: string, appointmentTime: string, name: string, email: string, phone: string): Observable<Appointment> {
    return this.http.post<Appointment>(`${this.BASE_URL}/appointments`, { appointmentDate,appointmentTime, name, email,phone});
  }

  cancelAppointment(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.BASE_URL}/appointments/${id}`);
  }
}
```

Here is my definition of my API_URL inside my enviorment.ts/enviorment.prod.ts files, im not sure what to put inside of this.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:3000',

};
```

Comment: Did you check network inspect in browser? Need to check what endpoint does your site reach actually

Comment: @development-ninja What do you mean, like check it when its deployed to firebase or locally?

Comment: @development-ninja this is what it tells me 
POST http://localhost:3000/appointments net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Okay that means api not found because the url path shouln't contain localhost when it is deployed to live server. You should handle path to ensure api should be working.

Comment: @development-ninja should i just remove the API_URL variable then? or leave it blank

Comment: Wait sec, let me tell you solution in your code.

Comment: @development-ninja ok, Thank you

Comment: What is your live url?

Comment: @development-ninja qdayclinic.web.app

Comment: @development-ninja you're supposed to be able to see all POST requests on https://qdayclinic.web.app/appointment-list.     They are supposed to be displayed on a table

Comment: Did you try what I have mentioned in answer? Can you please give me feedback? thanks.

Comment: @development-ninja I have not been able, I have been busy with my other job, and Finals. Will try/update tomorrow, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make your local api to be hosted on https:// by hosting your app on firebase cloud function.
Once you make it then please test it returns same result in same response type as your localhost:3000/appointments.
Firebase cloudfunction is serverless function which communicates via https protocol. The exported url will be `https://us-central1-..`

And update your angular frontend to change base_url to have above api without `/appointments` to ensure it can be accessed via https live hosting.
Make this cloudfunction on your admin

```
// cloudfunction
exports.appointments= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  
  return cors(req, res, () => {  //its good for you to install cors package on your cloud function side to avoid any cors error. npm install cors
    //your code here
    return res.status(200).send(result)
  });
});
```

```
// your angular frontend
export class AppointmentService {
 //your code
 private BASE_URL = "https://us-central1-.."   //your cloudfunction url without /appointments. this is root url of all your apis
```

Then build and deploy again.
Atleast we should see the hosted live site access to https endpoint which were made by cloudfunction

[image]

Comment: That means the update of url has not been affected to hosted site.

Comment: Then just replace BASE_URL to have `http://qdayclinic.web.app:3000` instead of getting from `environment`? We need to make url to absolute path like above in hosted site.

Comment: It is not updating the base_URL when i deploy for some reason

Comment: Please try to update in your angular frontend code and dont include from environment file then. Just replace Base_URL to have constant value in your angular frontend code.  Just try to make sure firebase deploy works alright.

Comment: I am afk in 15 min. Please let me know if that works. Or lets do via screensharing why fb deploy and doesnt see update in your hosted site when I return.

Comment: Yeah deploy or something is not working, it has to be something with fb, i am hardcoding the base_URL in, and still nothing is happening. How can i screenshare with you, discord?

Comment: Interesting, if you use `ng build` or I dont know what command you use to build. anyhow please check build file is correct that having updated url.

Comment: Yeah When I run it "local" it shows "POST http://qdayclinic.web.app:3000/appointments net::ERR_FAILED "

Comment: Ok as I see it is updated. now as I see your live hosting is https but it is trying to reach to http which is unsafe, that cause error. We should host api on https which is safe and can be accessed on https server. So please make a cloud function on your firebase and run api on there. Eg your api `/appointments` should be hosted on cloudfunction which support https. And then use that https url on your angular frontend to access.

Comment: Let me hear your progress and let me know.

Comment: I tried doing this, but my BASE_URL is not updating after I deploy

Comment: I have checked the firebase logs to see if the deploy was really successful, and everything. I have tried to disable cache on the page I was using to access the qdayclinic.web.app URL, but when I click on the button and look inside the console I am still getting that it is connected to qdayclinic.web.app:3000/appointments as the POST, and that I can't do it because of mixed http/https, Somehow FB is not updating the URL i have in the ts file.

Comment: We absolutely should need to call https endpoint in https hosted live site. Thats why I recommended to host api on cloud function. Did you host your api on cloud function to have url as https://..? And update doesn't work is different problem. If you still get issue on deploying update fail then let me know.

Comment: Yeah it is still giving me the error, and even when I try to deploy the frontend some of it is not updating, i've tried to clear cache/restart/local deploy before i deploy.